# Unable to call a variable from another class c#

Tags: c#, variables, .net-3.5, public

I have the following class in my c# application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Citrix_Killer
{
    public static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
        string name = Myfunc.userName();
        List<string> servers = Myfunc.get_Servers();
        string[] session = Myfunc.get_Session(servers, name);

        string sessID = session[0];
        string server = session[1]; 
        string sessName = session[2];  

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Where sessId, server and sessName all have appropriate values.
In my Form1.Designer, I want to call these details to display on the form (the text for button1):

```
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = Program.sessName;
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

However

But I am seeing this error: The type or namespace name 'sessName' does not exist in the namespace 'Citrix_Killer' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This also fails when using just sessName - can someone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: sessName is not a public property of Program

Comment: Make sessName public by `public sessName = ..`

Comment: `sessName` is only available within the scope of Program.Main(). If you want to access it from another class, declare it as a class-level variable and make it public.

Comment: The solution is to pass the required values to `Form1` via its constructor. Please see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to pass the required values to `Form1` when creating it. For example, assuming you want access to `sessID`, `server` and `sessName`, change `Program.cs`:

```
namespace Citrix_Killer
{
    public static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            ...
            Application.Run(new Form1(sessID, server, sessName));
        }
    }
}
```

And change `Form1.cs` to accept the values in its constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly string _sessId;
    private readonly string _server;
    private readonly string _sessName;

    public Form1(string sessId, string server, string sessName)
    {
        _sessId = sessId;
        _server = server;
        _sessName = sessName;
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
    }
```

Then you can reference them in your initialisation code:

```
    // 
    // button1
    // 
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = _sessName;
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Comment: Thanks David, very well explained and a great example. If you get a chance could you please let me know why you are setting the variables to private readonlys in the Form1 class? Thanks

Comment: @basijan, as the values are being calculated at app startup and passed to the object via the constructor, they shouldn't change. It's therefore a good idea to reinforce this fact by making them `readonly`. Should the need arise for them to change later, the compiler will prevent possible breaking changes being made to them within `Form1` and will encourage you to rework the solution to properly handle the need for them to change at runtime.